# configuring post on like of Facebook app

Tags: facebook

I am having a facebook app with like button inside the app. How to configure a post, when my app users click on like?

Right now when users click on like, a wall post is done which is giving app url and image.

I want to configure my app name, my website url(instead of app url) and description so that when user clicks on like the post will contain these by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the name, URL and thumbnail etc via the [open graph headers](http://ogp.me/) Facebook's documentation is little disappointing - it will bamboozle you with information about actions and stories, ignore it - look at the http://opg.me pages for more info. Basically, you need to add the following headers to your page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Awesome App" />
<meta property="og:type" content="application" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://my-app-url" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://my-app-url/image.png" />
```

You can then test these out using the [Facebook Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug%E2%80%8E). Paste into the tool the URL which the Like button is for - it will show you the information which Facebook will display when a user likes that link.